# Table data does not display properly after append in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to use AJAX for searching a project ID and display it.

This is what it looks like before the AJAX call

[image]

However when I try to search this is what happens when I try to append to my table body

[image]

This is my AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : '<?php echo base_url('View_projects_controller/getProjectID'); ?>',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data : {project_id : project_id},
                    success : function(data){

                        $('#tablebody').empty();

                        var status = "";
                        var status_class = "";
                        var action = "<?php echo base_url('View_controller/viewProject') ?>";

                        $(data).each(function(){
                            console.log(data);
                            if((this.approval_status == 0) && (this.reason_for_rejection == null)){
                                status = "Approved";
                                status_class = "label label-success";
                            }
                            else if(this.reason_for_rejection != null){
                                status = "Rejected";
                                status_class = "label label-danger";
                            }
                            else{
                                status = "Pending";
                                status_class = "label label-primary";
                            }

                            $('#tablebody').append('<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="'+ action +'">' +
                                '<tr>' +
                                    '<td>' +
                                        '<input class="hidden" name="project_id" value="'+ this.id +'"/>' +
                                        ''+ this.id +'' +
                                    '</td>' +
                                    '<td>' +
                                        ''+ this.project_title +'' +
                                    '</td>' +
                                    '<td>' +
                                        ''+ this.office_name +'' +
                                    '</td>' +
                                    '<td>' +
                                        ''+ this.date_submitted +'' +
                                    '</td>' +
                                    '<td>' +
                                        '<span class="'+ status_class +'">' +
                                            ''+ status +'' +
                                        '</span>' +
                                    '</td>' +
                                    '<td>' +
                                        '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-link" name="action">View</button>' +
                                    '</td>' +
                                '</tr>' +
                            '</form>');
                        })
                    },
                    error : function(errorw) {
                        alert('Error');
                    }
                });
```

The problem lies on the part `$('#tablebody').append()` when I try to remove the starting and ending `<form>` tags. This is what happens

[image]

It displays correctly.

However, I cannot remove the form tags as I need it to go to another page when the view button is clicked.

How can I overcome this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's normal because you can't wrap a `TR` element with `FORM`.

Comment: So should I put `FORM` inside `TR`?

Comment: I dont think that is a better alternative , by the way form is not only the option if you want to go to otherpage

Comment: But why is it that my original work where i wrap the `TR` element with `FORM`, it works? Refer to the first picture.

Comment: I'm sorry as I'm quite new in web development. What other alternatives are there?

Comment: Hi @CronasDeSe, I think you can put the whole `table` inside a `form`(not the `tablebody` only) and then need not to append the `<form>....</form>` everytime. Then  you can just put the `<tr>......</tr>` inside `tablebody` and make sure from the original design, that you have not missed any `class` at the of appending `elements` from javascript.

Comment: Thanks @Avishek Chat, I tried doing that but as you can see, there are many `view` buttons which submits the form. How will I know which `view` button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

If you open form tag and add tr inside it, it breaks the form tag. To fix this add form inside tr.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code as **form** ($('#tablebody').append('....')) tag create problem. 
Steps you need to do:-

- Remove Form Tag from $('#tablebody').append()
- Now you need to do something to achieve **form** tag task
- So make a function like (First provide a class to submit button then)

> $(".class-of-submit button").click(function(e){
>          //now get all data from row in object
>          $(this).closet("tr").and find all data 
>          //now submit your data to perform action
>   })